# How to create relational database structure for Elasticsearch using nested

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I have relations in my database. I have tables: books, chapters, and paragraphs. I keep id in paragraphs (`book_id`) and chapters (`paragraph_id`) tables, so in mapping I use `nested`. In Laravel's model `Publication.php` it's the code:

```
        'title' => [
            'type'     => 'text',
            'analyzer' => 'polish',
        ],

        'chapters' => [
            'type' => 'nested',
            'properties' => [
                'name' => [
                    'type'     => 'text',
                    'analyzer' => 'polish',
                ],

                'title' => [
                    'type'     => 'text',
                    'analyzer' => 'polish',
                ],

                'paragraphs' => [
                    'type' => 'nested',
                    'properties' => [
                        'name' => [
                            'type'     => 'text',
                            'analyzer' => 'polish',
                        ],

                        'title' => [
                            'type'     => 'text',
                            'analyzer' => 'polish',
                        ],

                        'authors' => [
                            'type'     => 'text',
                            'analyzer' => 'polish',
                        ],
                    ],
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ];

    public function chapters()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Chapter::class);
    }
```

in `Chapter.php`

```
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Publication::class);
    }
    public function paragraphs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Paragraph::class);
    }
```

and in Paragraph.php

```
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Chapter::class);
    }
```

My problem is that Elastisearch doesn't see relations between models. In Kibana it's really simple to uploads data with nested structure, but I have an issue with doing that using Laravel and data mapping from a database. 
Is it even possible or maybe it's a bad practice?

Comment: Did you read this? https://medium.com/@babenko.i.a/how-to-make-laravel-and-elasticsearch-become-friends-55ed7690331c  , you need to map the id fields too, elastic need to know the "foreign key" in order to join the nested documents.

Comment: I used https://appdividend.com/2018/06/30/laravel-elasticsearch-tutorial-example/ and I'm able to searching through first model (Publish).
With tutorial from medium I have error 400 and I don't understand when mapping is called, but when I call for example ```Publish::all()``` with relations mapping is correct.